# How do I parse two arguments into two variables of type double?

Tags: parsing

I would like to know how to take two numbers that are separated by a comma (for example 8, 3) that are in the run arguments line and parse them into their own variables of type double.

For example, double var1 = 8 and double var2 = 3. I have tried to use parseDouble() to do it but since the string whose values I'm trying to parse into variable are in the run arguments line, Will I have to deal with the String args[] as the string I'm trying to parse?

Comment: What language are you using? Can you include in the question the code that you have tried? Use a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Answer (score 0):

Try parseFloat:

```
var1 = parseFloat("3.00") + "<br>";
var2 = parseFloat("8.00") + "<br>";
```